# How to add gradient colors above chart line android?

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart, linechart

[image]

How to add gradient above the line in mpandroidchart.Thanks in advance?

Comment: I think you need to draw the line below 0 yaxis to make the gradient on top the line, so you need to manipulate you y value data

Comment: But i need positive values. If I am drawing below Y axis then the values and y-axislabels will be negative right?

Comment: you can set custom value formatter for y axis to show a positive value label

Answer (score 0):

[image]

fade_red.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:startColor="#00ff0000"
        android:endColor="#ffff0000" />
</shape>
```

CustomValueFormatter

```
    class CustomValueFormatter extends ValueFormatter {

    int maxValue;

    public CustomValueFormatter(int maxValue) {
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        int newValue = (int) value + maxValue;
        return  newValue + "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getPointLabel(Entry entry) {
        int newValue = (int) entry.getY() + maxValue;
        return  newValue + "";
    }
}
```

chart data & setup

```
chart.setDragEnabled(true);
    chart.setScaleXEnabled(false);
    chart.setScaleYEnabled(true);
    chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    chart.getXAxis().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    chart.getDescription().setText("");
    chart.setTouchEnabled(true);

    ArrayList<Entry> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int maxValue = 1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(new Entry(i,  (100 * i) - 1000));
    }

    chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMaximum(0);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setAxisMinimum(-maxValue);
    chart.getAxisLeft().setLabelCount(5);

    CustomValueFormatter valueFormatter = new CustomValueFormatter(maxValue);

    chart.getAxisLeft().setValueFormatter(valueFormatter);

    LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(list, "");
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.orange);
    dataset.setColor(color);
    dataset.setDrawCircles(false);
    dataset.setDrawFilled(true);

    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.fade_red);
    dataset.setFillDrawable(drawable);

    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> sets = new ArrayList<>();
    sets.add(dataset);
    LineData lineData = new LineData(sets);
    lineData.setValueFormatter(valueFormatter);
    chart.setData(lineData);
```

Comment: what about the values inside chart.Any help with that?